# Differential equation help with a problem true/false

Tags: proof-explanation, problem-solving

The answer is TRUE and FALSE but for the first question I don't even understand what is asked? what is H(x,y)? Why is it True?

[image]

Comment: Look up implicit differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

Take $y(x) = -x^2$ and notice that it satisfies the equation. I would say that you can take $H(x,y) = y+x^2$. Notice that $H(0,0)=0$ and hence $H(x,y(x)) = H(0,0)$ turns to be
$$ y(x) + x^2 = 0, $$
that gives $y(x) = -x^2$, i.e., the solution to the differential equation. 
This proves that the first claim is true.